# Can @PreAuthorize annotation throw exceptions?

Tags: java, spring-security

I wrote my own security service to validate access to methods using @PreAuthorize annotation. It is working fine with methods that returns true or false, but in some methods i want return true or throw specific exception. It looks like this:

```
public boolean validateAccess(String code) throws MyException{
    if (contidions){
        return true;
    }
    throw new MyException(code);
}
```

And I use it this way:

```
@PreAuthorize("@securityService.validateAccess('aaa')")
public void methodName(){
    //stuff to do
}
```

Unfortunately it is not throwing exception if conditions not satisfied, but expression evaluation error occurres.

Is there any way to throw specific exception from @PreAuthorize annotation?

Comment: I don't think @PreAuthorize expressions are supposed to throw exceptions.